# How to convert a string of as.factor to as.numeric in R?

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a data set as follows:

```
sample tmt key value
1       1   t0  11
1       2   t0  12
..
..
100     4   t100 121
```

I have ~400 such rows. The key has values like `t0, t01, t03, t100` that represent time in days eg. t0 is 0 days, t01 is day 1, t100 is day 100.

Currently the structure of the key is `as.factor`

I need to convert the key into a `as.numeric` function such that it reads as `0,1,2...100`. For each sample there are several associated t0s, t1s etc. Is there an easy way to do it without manually replacing all the t0, t1 .. etc?

Comment: Can you just not replace `t` with an empty string (`sub('t', '', df$key)`) and then convert to `as.numeric` ?

Comment: That did the job! Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gsub` to substitute.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  sample = 1:100,
  tmt = 1:100,
  key = as.factor(paste0("t", 1:100)),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

df %>% mutate(key = as.numeric(gsub("t", "", key)))

# # A tibble: 100 x 4
#    sample   tmt   key       value
#     <int> <int> <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1      1     1     1 -1.92796670
#  2      2     2     2  0.32439762
#  3      3     3     3 -1.09627047
#  4      4     4     4 -0.11293941
#  5      5     5     5 -1.33618028
#  6      6     6     6  0.26458634
#  7      7     7     7 -0.31001779
#  8      8     8     8 -0.76220697
#  9      9     9     9  0.09226835
# 10     10    10    10  1.27032132
```